# Combining a scrollable Gradient with a fixed image

Tags: html, css

m trying to combine a scrollable gradient with a background-image that is fixed to the bottom of the screen within the same element.

```
.wrapper {
background-image: url('../resources/City_side3.png'), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 205, 164, 1) 0%, rgba(159, 78, 117, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 49, 1) 100%); /* W3C */
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom;
background-attachment: fixed;
height:auto !important;
height:100%; 
min-height:100%; 
}
```

my issue here is that the background-attachment also fixes the gradient, is there any way to fix the image seperately?

Comment: Why do you set the gradient twice, once in wrapper and once in wrapper:before?

Comment: Ya my bad, I was attempting a solution and copy pasted it

Comment: If body will be scrolling then set the gradient on the body, not the wrapper as that one will not move, or will the wrapper contain scrollable content? ... If you could provide the html code as well it would help.

Comment: That was my original idea, however because of sizing issues, I moved it out of the body/html.  your suggestion works fine whenever i have content that exceeds the viewport, but when that doesnt happen i run into issues, which is why id like to use it in this one element

Comment: Are you aware that you are not adding another backbground to your wrapper element with `.wrapper:before`, but a pseudo element as first child of this wrapper? This pseudo element will not be visible unless you give it a width or `display: block;` and some content `content: ' ';`

Comment: What issue do you ran into when content doesn't exceed the viewport? .. Can you post a screen dump showing it?

Comment: Thomas you were right, the wrapper:before element was not visible, I have removed to avoid more confusion.  As for my previous issue, when the contents of my page were smaller then the viewport it would cut off my image, the same one im trying to combine with the gradient

Comment: for the wrapper's `height:100%;` to have effect you need to set 
`html, body {height:100%;}`

Comment: I have already done this, and I get exactly what the code gives me, a fixed gradient along with a fixed image placed on the bottom.  Id like for the gradient to stretch out so that i can see the colors as i scroll.

Comment: not sure, if that is what you want?
`background-attachment: fixed, scroll;`

Comment: same as with background-image you can set other background properties like background-repeat, -position, -size, -clip, -olrigin and -attachment also for multiple backgrounds. Only exception is background-color, which applies for your last background. [MDN:Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

Comment: And here´s a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbnabncf/) - let me know, if that is what you want to achieve

Comment: Thomas the fixed, scroll was exactly what i was looking for, thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90465/discussion-between-tomd1990-and-thomas-baumgartner).